# Hibernate generate predefined entity identifier

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

Firstly I am new to hibernate. I am developing an application for my office and i have been asked to use a specific id which should come like this ("YEARMONTHDATE"incidentnumber of that day).

As an example, if an incident reported on February 2nd 2015 and the incident is the third one for the day, the id should be like "2015022003".

I need to know how this can be done in Hibernate. Most importantly the last two digits should come after checking the last record and the date too.

Comment: That is a violation of 1NF. Is this really an obligation that you do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should encapsulate all this logic into a `store procedure` and then add a database [BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html) to assign the primary key to the output value of the stored procedure call.

In Hibernate, you have to use a `select` identifier generator:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(generator="trigger-generated")
@GenericGenerator(
    name="trigger-generated", 
    strategy = "select"
)
private String id;
```

Comment: I tried to convert my java code i had before to a store procedure. but a small issue. in java i can split my strings.but in store procedures, is there any function that i can use to split my spring to check the date? i have to have two strings, the date and the index number to generate the next value